# How to implement logical AND and OR operator in one query using django

Tags: django, python-3.x, mongoengine

I am looking to implement AND and OR logic in my Django query but after checking a lot of posts and searching I found that I can not implement AND-OR logic in the same query filter.

Here is what I want to achieve

**I want to fetch records which have key ABC AND values Value1 OR Values2 OR Values3 AND key CDE AND values Value4**

I am using `python3.6, django1.11, mongoengine, and MongoDB`

```
filter =  [ { "Key": "ABC", "Values": ["Value1", "Value2", "Value3"]}, { "Key": "CDE", "Values": ["Value4"]} ]
```

Response:

```
[  
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ebd29286310619f046ba866"),
        "account_id" : "12",
        "key" : "ABC",
        "Value" : "Value1"
    }

    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ebd29286310619f046ba866"),
        "account_id" : "12",
        "key" : "ABC",
        "Value" : "Value2"
    }

    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ebd29286310619f046ba866"),
        "account_id" : "12",
        "key" : "ABC",
        "Value" : "Value3"
    }

    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ebd29286310619f046ba866"),
        "account_id" : "12",
        "key" : "CDE",
        "Value" : "Value4"
    }

]
```

This is what I have already tried but got an error **mongoengine.errors.InvalidQueryError: Cannot resolve field "key"**

```
from mongoengine.queryset.visitor import Q
records = MyModel.objects.get(Q(key__exact='ABC'),
    Q(Value__exact='Value1') | Q(Value__exact='Value2') | Q(Value__exact='Value3', Q(key__exact='CDE'), Q(Value__exact='Value4')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Q` object, which is mentioned at [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q). As an example:

```py
Poll.objects.get(
    Q(question__startswith='Who'),
    Q(pub_date=date(2005, 5, 2)) | Q(pub_date=date(2005, 5, 6))
)
```

this code equivelent to:

```
SELECT * from polls WHERE question LIKE 'Who%'
    AND (pub_date = '2005-05-02' OR pub_date = '2005-05-06')
```

Comment: Hi @Deniz Thanks for the response, I have tried this but I got an error.

Comment: I have added code that I tried, please note that I am using mongoengine Q and Django Q

Comment: I think is is about capital 'K' of 'Key', can you try with `Q(Key__exact='CDE')`?

Comment: But I DB I have field key and Key, I have tried this also it is not working,

Comment: As the error indicates, there is a mismatch about key field. Maybe your model definition and database scheme not same. It may cause this error. This answer may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25515226/2474573

Comment: Hi @ Deniz, you were right, it was serializer causing this problem, Thanks.